# how do i run a java associated program via batch file commands?

Tags: executable-jar

I have a .jar program that runs with jre-installed, when i run it, it abruptly exits. I want a command written in notepad or something on Windows platform that can execute this .jar file.
Something like @Echo off COMMAND

I wrote the code
@echo off
setpath = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_191\bin\java.jar

Expected to execute some file called Client.jar

Comment: you should be able to run a jar from the command line with a command like `java -jar <jar-file-name>.jar`. The jar file must be a runnable jar with a main class